# Почему не работает cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookie, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте. Создаю куки, а почему то значение инпута не записывается в значение куки. Что я сделал неправильно?

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="Введите имя">
  <input type="button" id="done" value="Готово!">
</form>

<script>
  var init = function() {
  var expDate = new Date();
  expDate.setMonth(expDate.getMonth() +1);
  var cookieVal = document.getElementById("first").value;
  document.cookie = "first" + "=" + cookieVal + ";path=/;expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();
  var valArray = document.cookie.split(";");
  return valArray[1];
}
  document.getElementById("done").onclick = init;
  document.getElementById("first").value = init();

</script>
```

Comment: всё отлично записывается https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview , но не восстанавливается, возьмите скрипт для работы с куками на mdn :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework

Comment: здесь всё как надо, https://plnkr.co/edit/AGKxArz1FJg7nPtNNqhO?p=preview , у вас была ещё одна ошибка - попытка и считать и записать в одном месте, это не правильно.

Comment: Спасибо больше!

Answer (score 1):

Записывается. Только в cookie еще и другие значения находятся.

```
return valArray[1];
```

заменить на

```
return valArray[valArray.length - 1];
```